# Why LEFT OUTER JOIN reduces rows from left table?

Tags: mysql, join, correlated-subquery

Just want to show all data in table A and LEFT JOIN table B with coorelate subquery but fail to get all data in table A

```
SELECT a.id FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN tableB b1 ON a.id = b1.id
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableB b2 WHERE b1.id= b2.id)
```

```
tableA

id
======
1001
1002
1003
1004

tableB

id   date
=============
1001 20160101
1001 20160102
1003 20160102
1003 20160105

Expected Result

id   date
===============
1001 20160102
1002 NULL
1003 20160105
1004 NULL

Engine Return

id   date
=============
1001 20160102
1003 20160105
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do is a left join on a subselect, that only contains the max date per id like this:

```
SELECT a.id, b.maxdate FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date) AS 'maxdate' FROM tableB2 GROUP BY id) b ON a.id = b.id
```

This should also be quicker, since the select for the join will only be executed once while the select in a where clause will be executed for each row.

Answer (score 0):

update your query to be:

```
SELECT a.id, b1.date FROM tableA a 
LEFT outer JOIN tableB b1 ON a.id = b1.id
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tableB b2 WHERE b1.id= b2.id) or date is null
```

Comment: Change "WHERE" to "AND", and lose the "or date is null" bit - or just go with the better answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause applies on the joined dataset, therefore your where condition removes those records from the resultset, that do not match the criteria.

I would move your subquery to the from clause:

```
SELECT a.id FROM tableA a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(date) as mdate, id FROM tableB GROUP BY id) b1 ON a.id = b1.id
```

Comment: I think your subselect will return the MAX(date) of the whole table for each row, if it is not grouped by id, otherwise it's the same solution as mine ;-)

Comment: Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: It still ain't right, but seeing as Fuzzzzel's nailed it, a DELETE will probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You clear my concept, thanks!